# base58 prefixes

Tags: crypto, base58

Module `Prefix` in `src/lib_crypto/base58.ml` has lines such as `let ed25519_public_key_hash = "\006\161\159" (* tz1(36) *)`.

How does one get `"\006\161\159"` from `tz1(36)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base58 encodes characters by appending a prefix, treating the bytes as a big endian number and writing that big endian number in base 58.

Therefore, specific prefixes can pin down the most significant "digits" in Base58.

The python script `b58_prefix.py` in the `scripts` directory of the Tezos repo can help find those prefixes. Note that to run it you will need this version of the python lib `pybitcointools`

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools.git@aeb0a2bbb8bbfe421432d776c649650eaeb882a5#egg=master
```

Comment: How do you convert the byte array `"\006\161\159"` into a magicbyte value that can be passed to the bitcoin.bin_to_b58check function?

I discovered that you can use struct.unpack with the hex values of the byte array like this (generates p2sig(98))`P256_SIGNATURE = struct.unpack('>L', b'\x36\xF0\x2C\x34')[0]`, but `"\006\161\159"` is only 3 bytes so it can't be packed into a 4-byte big-endian integer.

Comment: see also the pending MR https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/1528 that documents this script further.

Answer (score 3):

Base58 prefixes will always produce a prefixed output for a set length of output. So the input address is 20 bytes + the 3 byte prefix gives a 36 char long address with tz1.

You calculate these prefixes by guess and check.